# visualization tree keep output the previous data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to process datasets in a jupyter notebook with 16 columns and 113000 rows, and when I try to create a graph tree with graphviz, it's normal at first but for the second and third tries it becomes very slow, and a warning appears: dot: graph is too large for cairo-renderer bitmaps. Scaling by 0.0564172 to fit. and the result is much different than before

what should have been just a few leaves and twigs now became much longer and bigger until I had to zoom in.

the command:

```
from six import StringIO
from IPython.display import Image
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,
 filled=True, rounded=True,
 special_characters=True, feature_names =
feature_cols,class_names=['0','1'])
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_png('contoh.png')
Image(graph.create_png())
```

im try to creating new notebook, different dir, restart the kernel, and creating new environtments and its all useless, the problem still come

in fact, I tried using matplotlib, but still the same